# Apply CSS to ul class then li then a

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of my footer items using CSS. I want to change the color of all `a` items as I have given same classes but do not know how to apply CSS.
Here is the code:

```
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>Our products</h4>
        <ul class="footer-items">
          <li><a href="#">About trade banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>Promo and Details</h4>
        <ul class="footer-items">
          <li><a href="#">About trade banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>About Our Services</h4>
        <ul class="footer-items">
          <li><a href="#">About trader banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: `ul.footer-items` ... `ul.footer-items > li` and `ul.footer-items > li > a` ? is that the part you can't understand?

Comment: @Bravo actually i wanted to change the color of all listed items to black but i do not know how to do that

Comment: Please learn to tag appropriately. This has nothing to do with `php` or `mysql`, and probably not with `javascript` either. (Tags removed.)

Comment: @Raja Jawad Kiani Check my answer, you can use that css to change color.

Comment: @Raja Jawad Kiani Can you please check answer and upvote / accept if useful?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser I already did that

Comment: @Raja Jawad Kiani Great! You can also check the checkmark below the downvote button next to the answer. Then this is marked as accepted answer so other visitor will know that this solved the problem.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser actually .footer-items > li > a this worked for me so I marked the answer true. Your answer was also helpful and its also working but I used above.

Comment: Good thing you've marked an answer that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.footer-items > li > a {
/*Your style here*/
}
```

with `.` you get the class.
with `>` you get the immediate child.

You need not write for every item individually, all matching items will get the styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the links text like this:

```css
ul.footer-items li a {
    color: red;
}
```

The color is applied to all `<a>` tags that have parent `<li>` that have partent `<ul>` with class `footer-items`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to give a class to the ul if you want to change all of the text color in ul a rater give the ul a css

```css
ul a {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>Our products</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About trade banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>Promo and Details</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About trade banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
        <h4>About Our Services</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About trader banner printing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delivery options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frequently added questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What our customer think of us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register for trade access</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```